# Transforming CURL request to Python using requests library

Tags: python, curl, post, http-headers, python-requests

Have a CURL request like that:

```
curl -X POST "https://page.com/login" 
-H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d "{ \"username\": \"admin\", \"password\": \"pass\"}"
```

In Python I guess it should look like this:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

data = {'username': 'admin', 'password': 'pass'}

response = requests.post('https://page.com/login', headers=headers, data=data)
response
```

After this it gives me [502] error for bad gateway. What am I doing wrong with my python query and how it should be modified?

Comment: try using `requests.post(..., json=data)` instead

Comment: cool thanks. you can post an answer I ll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
requests.post(..., json=data)
```

When you use `data=` requests will send it form encoded, to actually put json in the body you have to use `json=`